# Is this the site for medical research support discussion relating to machine and robots and software for medicine?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

Is this the right sight to discuss development of software interfaces and software tools used in medical research,

or is most of this subject private funded and proprietary?

I was wondering, mainly, about equipment used in the medical, pharmaceutical, biological, including medical imaging, molecule and pathogen identification, cure strategy, cure carrying out (procedure, and strategy implementation), medical devices used for surgery, including robotic surgery, programming microscopes (some Android phones even come with microscopes, last time I checked), devices and software used in medical imaging.

Is this the right site to find information about these issues, if at all possible, or do we need a new site to address these areas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you're wanting to know about:

> software interfaces and software tools

this would be appropriate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

> used in medical research

maybe [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/)?

But then you list a **lot** of other stuff, from programming microscopes to medical imaging to strategic implementation of medical aid (cure carrying out?).

It really depends on the scope of what you're trying to find out, but the key principle for all Stack Exchange sites is that they're appropriate if you're trying to *learn* about a topic. If you want to know [*how* x-ray imagining works](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64656/126492), then that would be an appropriate question for the Stack Exchange network, but if you're wanting to know what the packet structure is for the control panel of a particular x-ray device then that's something you would have to contact the manufacturer to find out.